# mysql > a join with duplicates on both sides, how to connect them individually.

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, duplicates

okay for example.

say i have in the fields.
A | B
A | B
A | B

I'm grabbing all the records that have A
and I'm joining to a table With B. The joined table
B | C
B | D
B | F

I want it to show up as:

A | B | C
A | B | D
A | B | F

But I think If I join it, it would only grab the first matching record and spit out:

A | B | C
A | B | C
A | B | C

How do I make it instead give me the results of each related individual record in the join?

Comment: just show your SELECT statement to fix, and expected data result you need

Comment: How are you expecting MySql to know which records from your second table it should match to which records in the first table, when the first table contains 3 identical records?

Comment: I'm hoping there's some way to tell it, "if it sees duplicates to link up. Just link them in by turns. 1st duplicate gets first record, 2nd duplicate gets second record, etc. Sorry, this isn't my table setup. I hate it.

Comment: that is not about table setup, it is more about your logic. what must happen if first table has 5 rows, 2nd - 3 and 3rd - 6 rows? where is your logic to assign records to each other? how many records must be returned?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular data and results, the following creates the output you want:

```
select distinct t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

Comment: Doesn't this just remover the duplicates? So instead of
getting all three records from the A. it will only spit out 1 record? which will only match once? returning 1 result,  A | B | C?

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicates, I want to link them up so they no longer look like duplicates.

Comment: You're mistaken about how SQL joins work. Your result set will contain all possible matches between records. A simple INNER JOIN on B of the first two tables you listed would return 9 rows, because there are 3 records in the first table, each of which can join 3 rows in the second. To get the result set you want, you need one record, A | B, which will join each of the three rows in the second table, yielding a result set with 3 rows.

Comment: @ChrisV . . . I don't know who your comment is directed.  If to my answer, then I think you are missing the `select distinct`.

Comment: and thank you @Gordon Linoff for the correct solution.